# Java read multiple objects from a file

Tags: java, io, text-files

consider i have 2 different classes

```
public class A {

    String name;
    int A1;
    int A2;

}
```

and the other class is:

```
public class B {

    String B0;
    int B1;
    int B2;
}
```

and now i have a file which contains an integer, and several object of A and several of B

The file could be like

```
3
"Jim"; 1;2
"jef";3;5
"Peter";6;7
"aa";1;1
"bb";2;3
"cc";3;4
```

You can consider that the**3** (in the beginning of the file)is the number of objects in class A and the rest are objects from class B.

The question is, how can i read and separate all  objects from the file?

The main problem is that i don't know how can i read the first int from the file. what i did is

```
     InputStream inputFileStream = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/inputFile.txt");
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream);      
int i = ois.readInt();
     ois.close();
```

but it gives me an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 350A4261
```

Comment: Your question is a multi-step question, and the steps include 1) reading lines from a file, 2 using loops to read in the first x A types, then a while loop to read the remaining lines 3) converting each line to an A or B type. So.... where **exactly** are you stuck? Show what you've tried please.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels i have edited my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The main problem is that i don't know how can i read the first int from the file.

You're reading a text file, not a data file, so don't use `readInt()`. Either use a BufferedReader, or my recommendation -- a Scanner object.

```
InputStream inputFileStream = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/inputFile.txt");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputFileStream);
int int = scanner.nextInt(); // get that first int
scanner.nextLine();   // go to the next line (swallow the end-of-line token)
//.....
```

---

Then use the same Scanner to read lines. Use

```
while (scanner.hasNextLine) {
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    // here process the line into an A or B depending on the results of a counter variable
    // then increment the counter here
}
```

Note that your processing will likely use the `split(...)` method of String to split on `;` and create an array of String with the items you need. You'll then need to parse the int related items via `Integer.parseInt(...)`

Comment: but when i go to the objects i have to change again my streaminput.
right?

Comment: @KamyarParastesh: heck no. Use the same Scanner. See edit above. You will want to try something and see what happens.

Comment: @KamyarParastesh: Any further questions?